# How can I create a drop down menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a fiddle that has the functionality I want. However, I'm not sure how to adjust the code (css) to get it to drop down the menu links.

When I click on the = I want the menu to drop down. The original code works by clicking on the parent and showing the child links. I assume it could work for my instance but not sure how.

What I want to accomplish is clicking the = drops Item 1 and Item 2. Otherwise they are hidden.

**HTML**

```
<!-- original code -->
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="parent">About
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>Johnny</li>
            <li>Julie</li>
            <li>Jamie</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>

<!-- my code -->
<div class="header-nav">
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});

// rename the JS to use the id/class for my script
```

The JSfiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/982/

Comment: Would be nice to explain why this was down-voted

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/cRsZE/985/ - probably downvoted because people on here are unforgiving :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to update the click event in your jQuery to work for clicking the menu icon. This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-icon').click(function() {
        $('.nav-menu ul').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

**Edit** As requested via the comments, to have the menu appear below the menu icon all you have to do is reposition the menu icon to be above the `ul` like so:

```
<div class="header-nav">
  <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/984/)

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to have the Items drop below instead of appear above?

Comment: See my edit, also updated the fiddle to work like you want

Comment: Thanks! It works in JSfiddle but not on my server. In the `<head>` element I have the jquery.min.js and another file called menu.js which has the JS code. Should it be in the body instead?

Comment: No, your references to .js files should be in the `<head>` tag

Comment: Hmm.. Can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I'm using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Would help the put the jquery.min.js about the other js file :)

Answer (score 1):

Need To update Code Like That :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#menu-icon').click(function() { 
$('.nav-menu ul').toggleClass('visible');
});
});
```

For Documentation :https://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up code a little. Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/cRsZE/990/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-icon').click(function () {
        $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```